# SQL - Group rows via criteria until exception is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add a Group column to a data set based on some criteria. For a simple example:

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ DATA ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║   12 ║
║  2 ║   20 ║
║  3 ║    3 ║
║  4 ║   55 ║
║  5 ║   11 ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

Let's say our criteria is that the Data should be greater than 10. Then the result should be similar to:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ DATA ║ GROUP ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║   12 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║   20 ║     1 ║
║  3 ║    3 ║     2 ║
║  4 ║   55 ║     3 ║
║  5 ║   11 ║     3 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

So, all the rows that satisfied the criteria until an exception to the criteria occurred became part of a group. The numbering of the group doesn't necessarily need to follow this pattern, I just felt like this was a logical/simple numbering to explain the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain how you get those groups with the condition "data greater than 10"?  I would get "1, 2, 3, 3, 4" as the group ids.

Comment: The first row met the criteria, the second row also met the criteria but the third row did not meet the criteria...So, every row that meets the criteria until an exception occurs gets grouped. Sorry if the original post was unclear

Comment: Why is the row with the value 3 put into its own group?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Following this grouping, I want to be able to count the items in the groups. It would be incorrect to say that there are 3 items in group 2 because really there are only 2 items that satisfy the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the group identifier by finding each row where data <= 10.  Then, the group identifier is simply the number of rows where that condition is true, before the given row.

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.id <= t.id and
              t2.data <= 10
       ) as groupId
from t;
```

SQL Server 2012 has cumulative sum syntax.  The statement would be simpler in that database:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when t2.data <= 10) over (order by id) as groupId
from t;
```

EDIT:

The above does not take into account that the values less than 10 are in their own group.  The logic above is that they start a new group.

The following assigns a group id with this constraint:

```
select t.*,
       ((select 2*count(*)
         from t t2
         where t2.id < t.id and
               t2.data <= 10
        ) + (case when t.id <= 10 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as groupId
from t;
```

Comment: it the 2*count(*) necessary?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with a recursive query:

```
;WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                1 AS [GROUP] 
         FROM   TABLEB 
         WHERE  ID = 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT T1.ID, 
                T1.DATA, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN T1.DATA < 10 THEN T2.[GROUP] + 1 
                  ELSE T2.[GROUP] 
                END [GROUP] 
         FROM   TABLEB T1 
                INNER JOIN CTE T2 
                        ON T1.ID = T2.ID + 1) 
SELECT * 
FROM   CTE
```

A working example can be found on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31d57/10)</kbd>.

Good Luck!